# MVC3 How to pass and assign FK field from one model to another

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have two models

First Model

```
public class Company
{        
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string CompanyName {get;set;}
   public virtual ICollection<Member> Member { get; set; }
}
```

Second Model

```
public class Member
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

So A company can have many Members

First, creating a company record and then I redirect to Member controller and when I try to save the Member record it fails.

Here is what I am doing: Id is the company id that is passed via ActionLink. Id I checked has a value. It fails when I want to assign the Id to Member's company_Id (FK)

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Member m, int id)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            **m.Company.Id = id;**
            db.Member.Add(m);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");  
        }
    }
```

When the member table is created, the fields that it creates
Id, name, Company_Id(FK)

What am I doing wrong? How do I assign the companyId to Member's Company_Id (FK)?

Thanks

Comment: i figured it out, if someone please confirm if it is correct and if it is the right way of doing it? and explain me why the previous way wasnt working (logic)... Changes I made: in the Create Method 

>Company company = db.Company.Find(id); company.Member.Add(m); db.SaveChanges();

Answer (score 0):

I think the Company is null and that is why. Do this:

```
public class Member
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public int CompanyId Integer { get; set; }
   public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

and in your action write:

```
//...
m.CompanyId = id;
//...
```

That should do the trick. If you want to read more about it look for navigation properties and foreign key properties.

Comment: still doesn't work, and I checked the company record, it creates the record in the db table but fails inserting company_id (fk) in the member table. Can you also provide if you know any example links to read about navigation properties and foreign key properties. thanks

Comment: also when I inserted public int CompanyId {get;set;} I got a compilation error:  The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "Member_Company". The conflict occurred in database "Test", table "dbo.Companies", column 'Id'.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: But are you sure that the company with the ID = `id which you provide in your code` exists in the database?